# How to avoid this warning:warning: com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.RE is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release

Tags: java

`private static RE          _TaskTypeRE                         = new RE("~:~([0-9]*)~");`

and this requires `import com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.RE;`

So on compiling I am getting the following warning.

```
 warning: com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.RE is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    [javac] import com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.RE;
```

One solution is to not use that class.

Another solution is to ignore the warning.
If i want to avoid this class what is the better alternative.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need regular expressions, use the [Pattern class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

```
private static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("~:~([0-9]*)~");
```

Take a look at the JavaDoc I linked to though. It may work differently.